# Naruto song during Gaara vs Sasuke fight in the forest

Tags: naruto, music

Does anyone know the song that plays on season 3 episode 24 of *Naruto* at 16:49 during Gaara vs Sasuke fight in the forest?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is Orochimaru's theme song. ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/ikmSfQmtq20))